# Why is Javascript not url-decoding the cookie value, and should it? How can I normalise the cookie encoding policy between languages?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I just noticed that when I `setcookie('foo','a@b.com',...)` in PHP and read it out in `document.cookie` in Javascript, the read-out value is `'a%40b.com'`

In the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Note that the value portion of the cookie will automatically be urlencoded when you send the cookie, and **when it is received, it is automatically decoded** and assigned to a variable by the same name as the cookie name. If you don't want this, you can use setrawcookie() instead if you are using PHP 5.

Seems like PHP is doing this a matter of its own policy, but Javascript (in Firefox) isn't playing the same game.

The data in question is unsanitised user input, so it *should* be encoded one way or another, for security and sanity purposes. Thing is, if I make Javascript use `decodeURIComponent` but then if the cookie is set by some other code/language/circumstance which *doesn't* have a policy of urlencodeing the value, then the decoding stage might yield an incorrect value.

I'd rather not hunt down every cookie-setting bit of code now and forever and consider manually normalising the encoding policy on each of them.

Is Javascript doing The Right Thing here? To what extent is this behaviour guaranteed? Can I set a HTTP header or something which will inform browsers of the cookie encoding scheme? Is there a fix-once-an-for-all solution for this?

Comment: This library might be something worth looking at in the meantime https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie